# Create a loop that creates files to a given directory

Tags: java, string, loops, file

I am trying to create a loop that creates files depending on some criteria. (Size of some database)

Problem is that it fails when I use a String reference as the name of the file, but it works fine if I directly create the string within the argument.

```
for(int i = 0; i < (sizeOf/dataPerFile+1) ; i++){
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String strDate= formatter.format(date);

            System.out.println((strDate+"_Backup"+i+".txt"));
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir").replace("/someproject", "")+"/backup/");
            new File((System.getProperty("user.dir").replace("/someproject", "")+"/backup/"+(strDate+"_Backup"+i+".txt"))).createNewFile();
        }

    }catch (IOException | SQLException | NumberFormatException a){
        System.out.println("Failed");
        System.out.println(a.fillInStackTrace());
    }
```

Failure Message

```
Connected
30/10/2020_Backup0.txt
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

My first guess is that my computer does not compute the given string values properly before it uses them. But not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share the failure message? does the code you posted depict the issue?

Comment: there are multiple issues and don't see your output matching the code. Try using java.nio.Files which has methods that will help you create directories before hand or use apache common library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the formatting of the date. The date has "/" characters in it, wich the file creator interprets as going to the next directory, try

```
strDate.replaceAll("/"," ");
```

Maby it works after that

Comment: that's needlessly complicating matters; just update the pattern string passed to SDF.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that all the subdirectories exist when you invoke `createNewFile`.

As the pattern `dd/MM/yyyy` is used for the file name, it means that directories `30/10` must exist inside `backup` directory.

This can resolved by using `File.mkdirs()` command to create the directory structure, and then creating files using constructor `File(String path, String filename)` to create a file in *existing* directory.

```java
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String strDate = formatter.format(date);

        String dirName = System.getProperty("user.dir").replace("/someproject", "") + "/backup/" + strDate;
        File dir = new File(dirName);

        if (dir.mkdirs()) { // create directory structure
            System.out.println("Created backup directory: " + dirName);
        }
        // create files when directory is available
        new File(dirName, "_Backup" + i + ".txt").createNewFile();
    }
} catch (IOException a) {
    System.out.println("Failed: " + a);
    a.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Note: it may be worth to change date format to `yyyy-MM-dd` to enhance grouping of the backups by date*

Answer (score 0):

You've formatted the date using forward slashes, so, the actual string passed is something like: `"/Users/theDev/projects/backup/30/10/2020_Backup0.txt"`.

That would try to create the file named `"2020_Backup0.txt"` in directory `"/Users/theDev/projects/backup/30/10"`. That doesn't work unless that directory exists, and it doesn't, so, you get an FNFEx.

Most OSes do not allow slashes in file names.

If really want this file to be created (I really doubt it), then do:

```
File f = new File(...);
f.getParent().mkdirs();
f.createNewFile();
```

and consider using the new file api (`java.nio.file`).

If you didn't want the file to be named like this, replace your SDF pattern with dashes or underscores or whatnot. And consider using the newer time API (`java.time`) - the APIs you are using are both obsolete.

> my computer does not compute the given string values properly

The computer does what the specs say it should do, which is therefore proper.

Your exception handler is broken; that's not how you do that. Generally, 'log it' is not 'handling it', so, throw any checked exceptions onwards (add `throws SQLException, IOException` to the signature of this method. Note that your `psv main(String[] args)` method can (and should!) be declared to `throws Exception`.

`fillInStackTrace()` overwrites the trace associated with an exception with the trace at the time you call fillInStackTrace - it is definitely not what you want (and it shows the wisdom of not writing 'just log it' in catch blocks: It's a violation of DRY and it's only an opportunity to mess up. The java infrastructure itself already does it better than you can.

If that is just not an option, then that means you're signing up to deal with it properly (and as we covered, 'log it', is not okay). If you have no idea, then, the 'I give up, I do not know what to do' code is `catch (SomethingICantReallyHandle e) { throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e); }`.

What you've done is removed a boatload of useful debugging info which, presumably, is why you're now asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

As most of the responses above answers, the error were within the date format with the forward slashes. - Those small but destructive mistakes...

Changed the date format's forward slashes and that fixed it. It is running great now. :-)

Thanks!